# Content Type application/x-gzip was not supported by service

Tags: c#, web-services

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 for consuming a webservice from an ERP system. When I try to call any method the following error occurs:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException' occurred in System.Web.Services.dll

Additional information: Server was unable to process request. ---> Erro ao inicializar RMSBroker: Content Type application/x-gzip was not supported by service net.pipe://localhost/RMSBrokerServer/IRMSBrokerServer.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.

Added the webservice link in option "Add" -> "Service Reference ..." usually without problems.

I do not know how to solve this problem in my client application.

Thanks,

Rodrigo

Comment: Sounds like you're sending x-gzip content (i.e. compressing the request) and the server doesn't support that.).  It looks like you're using net.pipe instead of http--gzip is typically only supported in http.

Comment: Hi Peter, I do not have access to the server. 
My application does just that:      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            wsRM2.wsDataServer i = new wsRM2.wsDataServer();
            i.Url = "http://172.16.2.27/TOTVSBusinessConnect/wsDataServer.asmx?wsdl";
            i.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("rodrigoml", "sssss", "dmcase");
            
            //wsRM.wsDataServerSoapClient i = new wsRM.wsDataServerSoapClient();
                                     
            string s = i.AutenticaAcessoAuth("user", "password");
        }

Comment: Your error message says you're connecting to your local computer, read the last line of the error message: "The client and service bindings may be mismatched".  I'd follow up on that first...

Comment: I understood what you said. However, do not understand how this can occur is that the proxy class was generated from the webservice server.